# Convert linq requests (queries) into one request without foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

I need convert this code into one request, if it's possible.

```
foreach (var obj in objs)
{
    if (obj.cars.Count > maxCars)
    { 
        var count = obj.cars.Count - maxCars;
        var cars = _carDao.GetQueryable()
                          .Where(v => v.obj.Id == obj.Id)
                          .OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedDate)
                          .Take(count);
     }
}
```

I have problem with `count`. I can use this request:

```
var ids = objs.Select(p=>p.Id);
var cars = _carDao.GetQueryable().Where(v => ids.Contains(v.obj.Id));
```

But I have different counts.

Comment: What do you do with the local `count` and `cars`? The last item meeting `obj.cars.Count > maxCars` would override any other previous assignments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
var query = objs
    .Where(o => o.cars.Count > maxCars)
    .SelectMany(o => _carDao.GetQueryable()
        .Where(v => v.obj.Id == o.Id)
        .OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedDate)
        .Take(o.cars.Count - maxCars));
```

Although i don't know why you need to query two sources.

Comment: Maybe `.Where(v => o.obj.Id == v.Id)`  ?

Comment: @user2889383: no, the other way around: `.Where(v => v.obj.Id == o.Id)`. But you're right, i've mistakenly selected from `o` on both sides.

Comment: @user2889383 `o` in `o.Id` is from `SelectMany`, not from `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see yourself executing a query, and then for each item making another query to a single source where it "matches" the current item in some way, it's a sign you should be using a `Join` operation (this applies not only to LINQ, but pretty much any use of a relational database).

```
var query = from obj in objs
    join car in _carDao.GetQueryable()
    on obj.Id equals car.obj.Id into cars
    select new
    {
        obj,
        cars = cars.OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedDate)
            .Take(obj.cars.Count - maxCars),
    }
```

Comment: I'm missing the `Where`, apart from that you answer seems to be better than mine. At least it is more efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't see the need for the first `Where`.  It just means that you're taking a negative number, so the resulting collection is of size zero.  If it's important that it in fact be there, it can be added in.  Without knowing how this is used, it's hard to say what's right.

Comment: I see the need because it's the first `if` in the `foreach`.